# Difference between azure storage accounts

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

Why Azure has given 3 different storage accounts. Is there any major difference between this account.

1. General-purpose v2 accounts
2. General-purpose v1 accounts
3. Blob Storage accounts

As 1 already can do everything in Azure storage like blobs, files, tables, and queue. 
Any suggestions appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several differences, most are in the limits/performances, additional supported features on the newer versions ex:

[image]

There are also replication cases which are not offered for specific storage account types, ex:

[image]

and finally a full overview which includes the above and adds on the Supported services, performance tiers and access tiers is below:
[image]